# Performing a Google search for .pdf and .ppt using keywords from a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, search, pdf

I am working on a program which performs a google search for .pdf and .ppt files. Currently I'm manually giving the keywords as inputs in my program. What I want to do is perform an automated search for both .pdf and .ppt files.

Suppose i have file.txt containing keywords:

```
    python
    android
    parser
```

I want my program to automatically take these keywords one by one and search for both .pdf and .ppt files.

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import json as m_json
def getgoogleurl(search,siteurl=False):
if siteurl==False:
    return 'http://www.google.com/search?q='+urllib2.quote(search)+'&oq='+urllib2.quote(search)
else:
    return 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:'+urllib2.quote(siteurl)+'%20'+urllib2.quote(search)+'&oq=site:'+urllib2.quote(siteurl)+'%20'+urllib2.quote(search)

def getgooglelinks(search,siteurl=False):
#google returns 403 without user agent
  headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/11.0'}
  req = urllib2.Request(getgoogleurl(search,siteurl),None,headers)
  site = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  data = site.read()
  site.close()

  start = data.find('<div id="res">')
  end = data.find('<div id="foot">')
  if data[start:end]=='':
  #error, no links to find
      return False
  else:
      links =[]
      data = data[start:end]
      start = 0
      end = 0
      while start>-1 and end>-1:
      #get only results of the provided site
          if siteurl==False:
             start = data.find('<a href="/url?q=')
          else:
             start = data.find('<a href="/url?q='+str(siteurl))
             data = data[start+len('<a href="/url?q='):]
             end = data.find('&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=')
      if start>-1 and end>-1:
          link =  urllib2.unquote(data[0:end])
          data = data[end:len(data)]
          if link.find('http')==0:
              links.append(link)
      return links
 keyword1  =raw_input('Enter the keyword as keyword+filetype: \n eg:python filetype:pdf' )
 links = getgooglelinks(keyword1,'http://www.google.com/')
 for link in links:
   print link

 query = raw_input ( 'Query: ' )
 query = urllib.urlencode ( { 'q' : query } )
 response = urllib.urlopen ( 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&' + query ).read()
 json = m_json.loads ( response )
 results = json [ 'responseData' ] [ 'results' ]
 for result in results:
   title = result['title']
   url = result['url']   
   print ( title + '; ' + url )
```

This is the code i'm working on. I tried using beautiful soup library; but it didn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't abuse `q` in google searches its against the terms of service to scrape page results

Comment: What is your specific problem? Do you not know how to open the file, how to parse its contents, how to use its contents in your query...?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to use the contents from my file to search google.

Answer (score 0):

So you are manually searching as in typing in the query to the program?

If that's what you are doing then you are almost there. You just have to do some basic file operations and instead of passing the user inserted query you will be passing each line in the file as query.

Make sure it is in string format such as `str(retrieved_data_from_file)` also with dictionary entries maybe like `mydict = {'q' : "'"+str(retrieved_data_from_file)+"'" }`
and close file after.